# Case insensitive sub-string first appearance replacement in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to perform a case insensitive sub-string first appearance replacement.

I've tried this code :

```
$product_name_no_manufacturer = preg_replace("/$product_manufacturer/i","",$product_name, 1);
$product_name_no_manufacturer = trim($product_name_no_manufacturer);
```

but it doesn't work in some cases.

When -

```
$product_name = "3M 3M LAMP 027";

$product_manufacturer = "3m";
```

the result I get is :

> "3M LAMP 027"

But when the parameters are different -

```
$product_name = "A+k A+k-SP-LAMP-027";

$product_manufacturer = "A+k";
```

the result I get is :

> "A+k A+k-SP-LAMP-027"

Why preg_replace doesn't replace the first appearance of `A+k`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`+`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) is a special character in Regex ("match the preceding token once or more"), so you have to escape it. Whenever you insert a string into your Regex, escape it with [`preg_quote()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php), because it can contain special characters (leading to seemingly strange results as in this case).

```
$quoted = preg_quote($product_manufacturer, '/');
$product_name_no_manufacturer = preg_replace("/$quoted/i", "", $product_name, 1);
```

Comment: Why are you escaping `product_name`? It is not a regex. You have to only use this function when you insert a string into your regex. Not on every variable that is in the close vicinity of a regex function. Use the example I have given and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

[`preg_quote()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) is what you are looking for.

Though

`. \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : -`

are special characters in a pattern, you have to escape them first (A+k becomes A\+k).

Edit: [Example here](http://codepad.org/cqPzJotL).

Comment: Your advice is correct, so +1, some nitpicking: `]{}=!<>:` are no special characters ( `]{}` only under defined circumstances, a `[` needs a closing `]` and `{}` only when they form a quantifier {1,2}, but {Foo,3} would be matched literally), `-` only in a character class, but escaping them does not hurt.

Answer (score 0):

`+` in regex have special means, you should escape it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this can be solved without any regular expressions. There is a useful function [strtr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php). So, you can use it like that:

```
$product_name_no_manufacturer 
         = strtr( $product_manufacturer, array( $product_name => '' ) );
```

This will be more faster than regexp and I think more convenient.